# Pros & Cons of "Memory Palace" vs regular "Working Memory"

Tags: memory, working-memory, mnemonic

Hi I'm trying to understand the limitations of the techniques which "memory champions" employ, in comparison to say: working memory.

Working memory seems quite limited, but it is at least fast to encode & access.
Also it seems to be able to encode arbitrary information (e.g. verbally).

How do memory palaces (& similar mnemonics) compare to working memory in terms of encoding speed & flexibility of content? Are all useful mnemonics extremely specialized/limited like the [major system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mnemonic_major_system)?

P.S. I would be particularly interested if you could give evolutionary context for your answer or why the brain works this way.

Comment: Welcome to psych.SE.  This question looks very similar to others on the forum: [Most efficient (highest-bandwidth) memory encoding scheme?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/25137/7001), [What does the literature suggest about the optimal strategy for quickly memorizing various types of content?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/1378/7001), and [Common latent feature among all "memory techniques"](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/24306/7001).  Not much in the way of answers though.

Comment: @ArnonWeinberg I appreciate the links. But I'm specifically wondering what properties of working memory mnemonics cannot emulate (e.g. perhaps encoding speed).